# if "it's" is short for "it is" why does "i don't know which version it's" sound weird?

Tags: grammar

I have never heard or read "it's" being used at the end of a sentence. Why is this not used?
another similar example is "this banana is yellow. If [it's] then why do you say it is red?"

What is the rule here? When can "it is" be shortened to "it's" and when not?
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only contract "it is" to "it's" when neither word has any *sentence stress*.

In both your example sentences, "is" has some sentence stress, so cannot be contracted.